# Contain HTML image size once they have been clicked on

Tags: html, css

I am looking to contain my image sizes once they have been clicked on,
currently they are shown larger than I wish for them to appear.

Example: http://messaages.com/post/144951542174

HTML: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4f09e3306f9b28ee0dce286342c51c7e

I have played around with various sizes within the code but I can't seem to be able to change it.

Comment: Can you add screenshots of what is happening and what you were hoping to have happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the image sizes once they are clicked on you will want to use javascript to change the css.

```
<img onclick="imageChange(this)" style="width: 200px; cursor: pointer;" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">

<script>
window.imageChange = function(image) {
        if (image.style.width === "200px") {
        image.style.width = "100px";
    } else {
        image.style.width = "200px";
    }
}
</script>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ws12fqzc/